# Any browser other than IE8 and below

Tags: html

I want some html to be displayed for any browser other than IE8 and below

I tried this but it didn;t work.  What's the correct syntax?

```
<!--[if !lte IE 8]>
     // my html here         
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: `<!--[if gt IE 8]>// my html here<![endif]-->` [How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use greater than:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
    According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 8<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Based on Mary Melodys comment you can also target everything apart from IE too! :

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: will this work for Chrome and Firefox.  It should show for them.

Comment: Conditional comments only work in IE. This will mean any internet explorer browser that is 8 or less will not show the content.

Answer (score 1):

To cover all bases, I thought I should give an answer about a third-party library like **jQuery**. This library adds a layer of java-script functionality to your website and comes with a range of functions for determining which browser is being used (as well as the version of that browser).

Here is the documentation to coding what you would like to achieve within jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

And here is a quick example of how this would work:

```
if($.browser.chrome) {
    alert( $.browser.version );
} else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    alert( $.browser.version );
} else if ($.browser.msie) {
    if ($.browser.version < 8){
        //Do what you will.
    }
}
```

Obviously if you are looking for a more lightweight / portable method then @iswinky's method is the way to go. However, if you are looking for a more heavy solution that supports a range of browsers then I would recommend this approach.